# Free option on a paid event

Tags: civievent, price-sets

We're running 5.10.4 on Drupal. We have an event where some folks will be requesting a scholarship and therefore need to be able to choose a $0 option. We also have an optional field where people can put in the amount they want to donate towards the scholarships. However, people cannot submit the page unless they have at least $1 in event fees.

https://www.zendust.org/civicrm/event/register?reset=1&id=283

Answer (score 3):

You have the value ‘1’ in the minimum amount field of the price set that you are using.

Visit the settings section of the price that’s being used and remove this value. It’s not mandatory.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had changed that, but apparently it didn't save. I changed it again and now we're good. :)